# Has anyone had success using Matomo for Shiny usage tracking with a shinydashboard app?

Tags: r, shinydashboard, matomo

I have been trying to get Matomo to work with a shiny app that uses shinydashboard and particularly dashboardPage but cannot get it to work. has anyone had success doing this?

I have tried using Sean Lopp's code (https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/usage-metrics.html). This works with a fluidPage but not with the dashboardPage.

If, instead of using dashboardPage as in the code below I use fluidPage I get the result I want and can see the tracker working.

When using this code I get the following error:

```
Error in tagAssert(header, type = "header", class = "main-header") : 
  Expected tag to be of type header
```

I have tried inserting the tags$head(HTML())) chunk in the dashboardHeader() and get the same error. If I place it immediately after the dashboardHeader I get:

```
Error in tagAssert(sidebar, type = "aside", class = "main-sidebar") : 
  Expected tag to be of type aside
```

This is an example of the code with dashboardPage. The identical code but with dashboardPage replaced with fluidPage works.

I would be grateful for any suggestions that anyone might have.

Thanks

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  tags$head(HTML(
    "<script type='text/javascript'>
  var _paq = _paq || [];
    /* tracker methods like 'setCustomDimension' should be called before 'trackPageView' */
    _paq.push(['setDocumentTitle', document.domain + '/' + document.title]);
    _paq.push(['setCookieDomain', '#########']);
    _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
    _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
    (function() {
    var u='###############################';
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', '9']);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
    })();
    </script>"
    )),
  dashboardHeader(title = "THIS IS A HEADER"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(),
  title = "Dashboard example"

)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to add it in the server. You simply put it in **dashboardBody()**
In your case:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "THIS IS A HEADER"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
     tags$head(HTML(
        "<script type='text/javascript'>
      var _paq = _paq || [];
        /* tracker methods like 'setCustomDimension' should be called before 'trackPageView' */
        _paq.push(['setDocumentTitle', document.domain + '/' + document.title]);
        _paq.push(['setCookieDomain', '#########']);
        _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
        _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
        (function() {
        var u='###############################';
        _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
        _paq.push(['setSiteId', '9']);
        var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
        })();
        </script>"
        ))

),
      title = "Dashboard example"
    

)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it in your server.R file. This is what I use:

```
output$renderPiwikHead <- renderUI({
# don't include stats if just running local development
if ((session$clientData[["url_hostname"]] != "127.0.0.1") 
  && (exists("PIWIK_SITE_ID") && !is.null(PIWIK_SITE_ID))) {
  # https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/usage-metrics.html
  # https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/packaging-javascript.html
  # Render the Piwik UX stats tracking at the end of <head>
  tags$head(
    HTML(paste0(
      "<!-- Piwik -->
                <script type='text/javascript'>

                var _paq = _paq || [];
                _paq.push(['setUserId', '", user_name, "']);
                /* tracker methods like 'setCustomDimension' should be called before 'trackPageView' */
                _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
                _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
                (function() {
                var u='https://piwik.sandia.gov/';
                _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
                _paq.push(['setSiteId', '", PIWIK_SITE_ID, "']);
                var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; 
                g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
                })();
                </script>
                <!-- End Piwik Code -->")
    )
  )
}
```

})

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks for your suggestion and sorry to take so long to respond. I have tried what you suggest and although I do not get errors I also do not get any tracking results coming through. I need to check more closely but have had to work on something else for a while. I suspect I have coded an error somewhere. I will check in the coming weeks and let you know if this works. Thanks for your patience! Best regards